# apply multilabel binarizer to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, multilabel-classification

I know how to apply multilabel binarizer on 1 column and it works for me.
For example, I do something like

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

binarized_df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['One']), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
```

However, I have 20 different columns to which I want to apply binarizer, and if I want to apply to all of them together, it does not work

```
cols = ['One', 'Two',...'Twenty'] 
binarized_df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df[cols]), columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
```

Is there a way to use multilabel binarizer for multiple columns all together?

Answer (score 0):

Since [`sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) accepts an *array-like* value for `classes`, have you tried just adding [`pandas.DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) to your code ?

> classes : **array-like** of shape (n_classes,), default=None

```
cols = ['One', 'Two',...'Twenty'] 

binarized_df = pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df[cols].values), 
                            columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
```

By the way, [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) might also work for you :

```
binarized_df = pd.get_dummies(df[cols], columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.index)
```

Comment: Yes, but since in row of df I have lists from which I want to create dummies, for example [cat, dog, insect, bird] it does not work with df[cols].values . And get dummies creates not what i want, for example, it gives a dummy just for naming the dog and also a dummy for namine dog and cat and then a separate dummy for dog, can and bird. And if multiplied by 20 columns it is a lot of columns to potentially drop

Comment: Can you try `pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.explode(x))))` **OR** `pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df[cols].pipe(lambda x: x.explode(list(x.columns))))` ?

Comment: It says ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis, not sure what it means

Comment: Can you add a minimal reproducible example (+with the matching expected output) to your question ?